# Send spontaneous ephemeral discord message

Tags: discord, discord.js

### TL;DR

Is there a way to send an ephemeral message to a user without using an Interaction ?

###### Usage

Interactions are a great tool to interact with user. Replying with ephemeral message is great too, to avoid notifying unrelated users.

Initiating an Interaction wouldn't be limited to SlashCommands, Users and MessageCommand but with reactions, specific content in messages, member nickname updates etc...
The iteraction would then pursue with ButtonsCommand in an ephemeral message.

I know I can use the old way (directly dm the user), but it would be more convenient to have an ephemeral message directly in the same channel.

###### Workaround

The only way I have found so far is having the user typing a command (or making any interaction that will act as an anchor point). And the later, when an ephemeral message is needed, make a follow up message from that interaction.

The downside of this solution is the user has to make an interaction in all channels that would require spontaneous ephemeral message. And also, users have to do an interaction in the first place, which isn't very convenient when you want to deal with new users.

Comment: I don’t believe this is possible yet. I mean if you think about it, you would have the specify the user. And that user may not even be online/available. However, with interactions (buttons, slash commands), you can be sure that the user is online and available. You don’t just want an ephemeral message sitting there for no one to see…

Comment: Yes, in my case i'm certain the user is online. But Discord will probably never implement a feature like this cause you would even have to specify the discord client which will display the message. With interaction it is easy to link back to the client, but with reaction or message I don't think there is a way to bound it to the client the user is currently using...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Ephemeral Messages FAQ](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000580222-Ephemeral-Messages-FAQ) and [Developer Documentation on Interaction Responses](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#interaction-response-object) show that only interaction responses currently support ephemeral messages.

There will not be any support for uninvoked ephemeral messages, [according to Mason](https://canary.discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/788586647142793246/837385603322347660), a Discord engineer ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxFdb.jpg)), as it would open quite a lot of abuse possibilities.

As [AEnterprise said in the Discord Developers server](https://canary.discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/788586647142793246/864815217078042644): "imagine bots being able to spam advertisements only visible to specific members, that are not stored [on Discord's servers] so very little to no proof for Trust & Safety to even look up".

Comment: At least being able to reply ephemeral to a regular message would be nice however

Comment: I agree, but it would still open up a lot of abuse possibilities. Another way to achieve this functionality would be to DM the user with some kind of a link or reference to the message.

Comment: users can have their DMs disabled however

Comment: There's nothing else that can be done then, except maybe creating a private thread from the message.